# jQuery: Insert img and change CSS when scrolled to a certain div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, scroll

Here's what I want to do:

Firstly, show the button image on the left of `<a>` tag within `<div class="side_list">` and change the color of `<p>` tag to indicate where the user is at, just like this if I honestly write it on html (but it has to be the first of the three entries on the list):

```
<div class="side_list">
 <img src="images/btn.png" width="20px" height="20px" alt="selected" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 9px;">
 <a href="#contentA"><p style="color: #53b6da;">Content A</p></a>
</div>
```

The others are like this, without the button image and font color specified:

```
<div class="side_list">
 <a href="#contentB"><p>Content B</p></a>
</div>
<div class="side_list">
 <a href="#contentC"><p>Content C</p></a>
</div>
```

Then if the browser is scrolled to the next div (#contentB), I want to highlight the corresponding entry on the list with the button image inserted and specified font color. At the same time, I want to switch off the highlight for #contentA, because we are not there anymore. I want to do the same with #contentC when it is scrolled down deeper.

How should I do this with jquery?

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
 <div id="side">
  <div class="side_list">
   <a href="#contentA"><p>Content A</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="side_list">
   <a href="#contentB"><p>Content B</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="side_list">
   <a href="#contentC"><p>Content C</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="main">
  <div id="contentA"></div>
  <div id="contentB"></div>
  <div id="contentC"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#body {
    width: 950px;
    height: 3000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

 #side {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

 .side_list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  }

 .side_list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
  }

 .side_list a p {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #main {
    width: 950px;
    height: 3000px;
  }

  #contentA {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #07CB6F;
  }

  #contentB {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #2FA3F7;
  }

  #contentC {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #FF00AB;
  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.side_list').first().find('a').addClass('active').append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAb0lEQVRoge3SwQ2AIBQE0SmB/puwBO1AOtKLxgLE/MXMS/ZKGAJIkiRJoRZgBVr1Rd7qwAHsTB7TMCaTMamMSWVMqk9i9uvAyg2JuV+mcn1ESIXG8xOMqGRECiNSGJHiFxHwkwiA7drUEZIkSZrMCfhPfOX9rM7NAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="20" height="20">');
  
    $('.side_list a').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
        var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('href'),
            scrollPoint = $(scrollAnchor).offset().top;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);
    });

   $(window).scroll(function() {
 var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $('#main > div').each(function(i) {
     if ($(this).offset().top <= windscroll) {
  $('.side_list').find('a.active').removeClass('active').find('img').remove();
  $('.side_list').children('a').eq(i).addClass('active').append('<img class="icon icons8-Right" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAb0lEQVRoge3SwQ2AIBQE0SmB/puwBO1AOtKLxgLE/MXMS/ZKGAJIkiRJoRZgBVr1Rd7qwAHsTB7TMCaTMamMSWVMqk9i9uvAyg2JuV+mcn1ESIXG8xOMqGRECiNSGJHiFxHwkwiA7drUEZIkSZrMCfhPfOX9rM7NAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="20" height="20">');
     }
 });
   }).scroll();
  
});
```

```css
#body {
    width: 950px;
    height: 3000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

 #side {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

 .side_list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
  }

 .side_list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
  }

 .side_list img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 10px;
 }
 
 .side_list a p {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }

 .side_list a.active p {
    color: red;
  }
  
  #main {
    width: 950px;
    height: 3000px;
  }

  #contentA {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #07CB6F;
  }

  #contentB {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #2FA3F7;
  }

  #contentC {
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #FF00AB;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div id="side">
    <div class="side_list">
       <a href="#contentA"><p>Content A</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="side_list">
      <a href="#contentB"><p>Content B</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="side_list">
     <a href="#contentC"><p>Content C</p></a>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div id="main">
  <div id="contentA"></div>
  <div id="contentB"></div>
  <div id="contentC"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is working great! Just want to make sure that it's okay to exclude `class="icon icons8-Right"` in <img> (javascript, 2nd line), right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var THRESHOLD = 920;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body,html').bind('scroll wheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var value = scrollTop / THRESHOLD;
    $(".side_list").removeClass('highlight');
    $(".side_list img").removeClass('visible');
    $(".side_list").eq(parseInt(value)).addClass('highlight').find('img').addClass('visible');
  });

});
```

CSS

```
    .highlight {
      background: grey;
    }
.side_list img {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block!important;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/ym2jph44/1/)

The class visible is added to the first image tag by default.